# Send data to running shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have continuously running script that waits for input and prints 'Wait for input' every 15 seconds to stdout. I need to emulate action of pasting list of IP addresses in stdin while script is running. For example manually i need to do these steps: copy list below including new line after last list element and paste it directly into stdin.

```
127.0.0.1
127.0.0.2
127.0.0.3
```

I've tried using pipes and redirections (with both \n and \r) from file with no luck

```
echo "127.0.0.1\n127.0.0.2\n" | script
```

or

```
script < file
```

where file contain same ip addresses. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please add the script to your question.

Comment: What unix is that? Is there a /proc available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a FIFO!

```
mkfifo /path/to/tmp.fifo
tail -f /path/to/tmp.fifo | script
```

Now whenever you send something to the fifo (from another TTY, from a process, whatever), it will be as if you typed into the waiting script, e.g.

```
echo "127.0.0.1" >> /path/to/tmp.fifo
```

Answer (score 0):

Use  `cat`.  If you execute:

```
cat | script
```

you can cut-n-paste or type into the tty.